# How to rotate image from N by M by P matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a variable X which is 32 by 32 by 32. I wish to `imagesc`this to display an image of the human brain. However, with the code that I run (see below) I obtain the following image:

[image: Brain rotated 90 degrees]

I would like to rotate this by 90 degrees so that the spinal chord is at the bottom of the Figure. I have already attempted algorithms such as `imrotate` and `flipdim`, but these just gives me a green screen.

My code thus far:

```
clc; clear all; close all;
set(0,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex',...
    'DefaultAxesFontSize',16,'defaultLineLineWidth',2) %use LaTeX
h1=figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]); %create Figure.
filename = 'testnew51.gif';
X = analyze75read('Anatomical.img');
Y=analyze75read('Mask.img');

hsurface=imagesc(squeeze(X(:,15,:)));
C=imrotate(hsurface,-90);

axis equal
colormap jet
shading interp

figure
B=flipdim(hsurface,1);
imagesc(B)

figure
imagesc(C)
```

Many thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Have you tried using `axis ij` or `axis xy` after the figure is shown?

Comment: @rayryeng this doesn't seem to do anything. I want the data rotated, not just the axis values.

Comment: Have you tried to use [rot90](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rot90.html?refresh=true) on your data?

Comment: Thanks @HamtaroWarrior - that did the trick.

Comment: It not only rotates the axis but the image as well. Not sure why it didn't work but I'm glad the other fix worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks *HamtaroWarrior*. The working code with cycling through the x axis is given below:

```
 X = analyze75read('Anatomical.img');
Y=analyze75read('Mask.img');
for i=1:32;
Xy=(rot90((squeeze(X(i,:,:)))));
imagesc(Xy);
title([num2str(i)]);
pause(0.5);
clear Xy
end
```